# How to find click event of button placed inside a repeater control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a div inside a repeater and inside the div i have a asp button, i want to access the button click event that button has clicked, here is my html code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ShoesRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4 grid-stn simpleCart_shelfItem">
            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item square effect3 bottom_to_top">
                <div class="bottom-2-top">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="images/<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>" alt="/" class="img-responsive gri-wid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="pull-left styl-hdn">
                            <h3><%#Eval("Category") %></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right styl-price">
                            <p><a href="#" class="item_add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart grid-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class=" item_price"><%#Eval("Price") %></span></a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end normal -->
            <div class="quick-view">
                <a href="Single.aspx"><span class="MenuItem" runat="server" onclick="LogOff_Click">Quick view</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Where  is the button? you have a anchor with inside a span with onclick.
You must use an asp:button or asp:LinkButton that have onclick event.

Comment: <a href="Single.aspx"><span class="MenuItem" runat="server" onclick="LogOff_Click">Quick view</span></a> 

Instead of this href m using a asp button 

<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

Check below,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ShoesRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4 grid-stn simpleCart_shelfItem">
            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item square effect3 bottom_to_top">
                <div class="bottom-2-top">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="images/<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>" alt="/" class="img-responsive gri-wid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="pull-left styl-hdn">
                            <h3><%#Eval("Category") %></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right styl-price">
                            <p><a href="#" class="item_add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart grid-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class=" item_price"><%#Eval("Price") %></span></a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end normal -->
            <div class="quick-view">
                <a href="Single.aspx"><span class="MenuItem" runat="server" onclick="LogOff_Click">Quick view</span></a>
                <!-- ADD BUTTON HERE -->
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Text='Test' runat="server" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In Code Behind,

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == Repeater1.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == Repeater1.Item)
    {
        var btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnSave") as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {  // adding button event 
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
    }
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //write your code 
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I think You can directly access the Click Event of Button even if its in Repeater Control..
Here is how i did.. ASPX Code

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="REPCOURSER">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <div class="thumbnail">    
                            <div class="descrip_progms">
                                <h3 class="text-danger">
                                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Cr_id") %>' class="btn btn-border yellow-2" Text="Add To My Courses" ID="btnAddToCourse" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddToCourse_OnClick_unat_" />
                                </h3>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                                <div style="background: #B6DA7C;height: 39px; padding: 9px;">
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-left" style="font-size: 15px;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblCrsName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cr_title") %>' />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-right" style="font-size: 15px;">
                                    <i class="fa fa-inr "></i>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblprice" CssClass="" runat="server" Text='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Cr_price").ToString())==0) ? "Free":Eval("Cr_price").ToString()+" Rs."  %>' />
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
 protected void btnAddToCourse_OnClick_unat_(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Email"] != null)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem re in REPCOURSER.Items)
            {
                Label rs = re.FindControl("lblprice") as Label;
                Button Addcourse = re.FindControl("btnAddToCourse") as Button;
                if (rs != null)
                { 
                    if (rs.Text.ToLower() == "free" && Addcourse != null)
                    {
                        Courses courses = new Courses();
                        int res = courses.EnrollFreeCourses(new Course()
                         {
                             CId = Convert.ToInt32(Addcourse.CommandArgument.ToString()),
                         }, new Users()
                         {
                             id = Convert.ToInt64(Session["Id"].ToString())
                         });

                        Addcourse.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                        Addcourse.Text = "Course Added To My Courses";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Procedure for paid courses

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Master.LoginPopupExtender.Show();
        }

    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "Button_Click", since you're in a repeater, you may want to consider letting the button trigger an item event and put your code in the item event.  If you have multiple buttons, you can look at the button's attribute to know which one it was.  You also get access to the item that was clicked on, in case you need it.

```
Protected Sub ShoesRepeater_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles ShoesRepeater.ItemCommand
  Select Case e.CommandName  'This is the clicked button's CommandName
    Case "b1"
      'Do stuff for Button1
      'e.CommandArgument is the clicked button's CommandArgument
      'e.Item.FindControl("lblPrice") allows you to access other controls in this same Repeater item as the button that was clicked.
    Case "b2"
      'Do stuff for Button2
  End Select
  'There's a decent chance you'll want to rebind the grid when you're done.
End Sub
```

P.S.  Sorry, that's VB.NET, not C# but you can find the correct place to put the code for ShoesRepeater_ItemCommand by using the dropdowns in Visual Studio, then use e.CommandName, e.CommandArgument and e.Item.findControl to access various values.  I just happened to use a Select Case statement to separate different buttons' code.

Comment: The other answers have parts that might work OK but cycling through the items in the repeater is probably not the most efficient and attaching the EventHandler at run time could make it harder to refer to other controls in the same repeater item, IF that's something you want to do.